# Fluent NHibernate: "...when a new object is created in memory, then it's identity field is undefined "

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fluent

Does anyone know how the object can be made so that it *does* have something in its identity field -  so that i can then use this to get the hash code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use Guid as id. This way you don't need database round trip to get identity value.

```
    <id name="_id" column="PersonId" >
        <generator class="assigned" />
    </id>
```

Or

```
Id(x => x.Id)
  .Column("PersonId")
  .GeneratedBy.Assigned();
```

'PersonId' column type should be [uniqueidentifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187942.aspx) if you use SQL Server. Then when you create object you can use [Guid.NewGuid()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.newguid.aspx) to generate new id.

```
public class Person {
    private Guid _id;

    public Person() {
        _id = Guid.NewGuid();
    }

    public Guid Id {
        get { return _id; }
    }
}
```

The advantage of this approach is that your code is more decoupled from database. This will be very helpful during tests and if you need to support 'disconnected' scenarios. Potential disadvantage is the performance during joins (google "guid vs int primary key"). See [this](http://barchitect.blogspot.com/2008/07/nhibernate-generator-and-primary-key.html) for additional information on id generators in NHibernate.

As a side note, you may want to [rethink](http://nhforge.org/wikis/patternsandpractices/identity-field-equality-and-hash-code.aspx) your design and implement your [Equals and GetHashCode](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/EqualsAndHashCode) using business key. You will not need Guid identity in this case. From [Don't Let Hibernate Steal Your Identity](http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2006/09/13/dont-let-hibernate-steal-your-identity.html?page=1):

> "We recommend implementing equals() and hashCode() using Business key
>   equality. Business key equality means that the equals() method
>   compares only the properties that form the business key, a key that
>   would identify our instance in the real world (a natural candidate
>   key)" (Hibernate Reference Documentation v. 3.1.1).

Comment: Thanks. Stackoverflow and its users never cease to impress me.

Answer (score 1):

WEll it depends on what kind of concurrency you want to achieve how long your unit of work is.. although GUId ids and HILO ids sound all fancy and cool most of the times they are not necessary.

regarding your problem you need to do a save on the database for the id to be generated provided the id is an auto incremented id generated by the db, this might hold a temporary lock on that table till your transaction is committed but that is one of the disadvantages of having an auto incremented id

and the other thing why would you save and compare the object against something else its bound to have a different id..

say Student is your class with two properties Id, Name, School

now if you want to see if its the same student then you probably want your hash generated on Name and School rather than Id

Comment: Yes now I am thinking of just creating a common-sense key in the object constructor, from fields.